# Configuring Mobile Account Using Google SMS

Tags: 2010, configuration, mobile, sms

The procedure to configure a mobile account for SP uses [SMSOffice.com](http://www.smsofficer.com/).

- Is it possible to configure mobile account to use [Google SMS](http://www.google.com/mobile/sms/) service? If you have done this please provide some insight.
- If integration with Google SMS is not possible, is there a no fee alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a free SMS service.

You could utilize the carrier specific email address (i.e. 8885551212@vtext.com for verizon) and either make that the primary email address (assuming you only want alerts via SMS and not email) or use some sort of forwarding rule on either you client or if you have access your mail server.

If you venture into custom solutions, you could configure the SMS contact address as a secondary contact for users and then create a custom event receiver that utilizes that SMS email to alert on changes.

Comment: It seems the Google SMS service is free.

Comment: Google SMS is part of other applications and you don't interact with it directly. There is no web address for instance to submit your SMS requests.  Google voice offers free SMS (google sms)service and SMS forwarding but no email or http methods.